# WPF DataGrid Blank Rows

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid, virtualization

I have a DataGrid with around 500000 virtualized items. When I scroll with the mousewheel or slowly up and down with the scrollbars, new rows are loaded without problem, but when I scroll by dragging the scrollbar (maybe over a range of 200000 or so records, I get a blank grid. The grid remains blank until I reinitialize the ItemsSource.

I'm using code from [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization), and my GridView loads items from the datacontext of the window. Is there something I'm missing or a more reliable way of virtualizing these items?

Answer (score 0):

you may check what are you set as datasource of datagrid. Is there data in the source?

Comment: there is when he scrolls small amounts with the mouse scroll wheel...so

Comment: My ItemsSource is the Window's DataContext, which is an ASyncVirtualizingCollction.

Comment: you really think that he can scroll by mousewheel almost 200000 items?

Comment: ASyncVirtualizingCollection works very slow. Are you sure that items is not loaded into datagrid? How many time are you waiting? Are there items is shown when you jump back by dragging scrollbar?

Comment: No, as I said in the original post, "The grid remains blank until I reinitialize the ItemsSource."

Answer (score 0):

Try using a VirtualizingCollection instead of a AsyncVirtualizingCollection.  Also, make sure that IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True".